# Can we deduce $\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{2i}\int_{\{ 2^i<|x|<2^{i+1} \}}|\hat{f}(x)|^2dx<C\|f\|_{H^1}^2$ from Littlewood-Paley theory?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral, littlewood-paley-theory

In today's class my teacher used the following inequality:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}\sum_{i=1}^\infty 2^{2i}\int_{\{ 2^i<|x|<2^{i+1} \}}|\hat{f}(x)|^2dx<C\|f\|_{H^1}^2,\end{equation}
where $\hat{f}$ denotes the Fourier transform.

While I was looking for this result I found the question [Use of the Littlewood-Paley decomposition to recover the $H^s$ norm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437395/use-of-the-littlewood-paley-decomposition-to-recover-the-hs-norm).  In particular, I have seen that
\begin{equation}\tag{2}\lVert f\rVert_{H^1}^2\leq \sum_{j=0}^\infty (2^j)^{2} \lVert P_{2^j} f\rVert_2^2\end{equation}
where $P_{2^i}$ is the Littlewood-Paley projectors defined as
\begin{equation}
(P_{2^j}f)^\wedge=\left[\phi\left( \frac{x}{2^j} \right)- \phi\left( \frac{x}{2^{j-1}}\right)\right] \widehat{f}(x),
\end{equation}
for $\phi\in C^{\infty}_0(\mathbb{R}^n)$ a bump function with $\operatorname{supp}(\phi)\subset\{|x|<2\}$ and $\phi(x)=1,\forall |x|<1$.

My question is: Is it possible to deduce $(1)$ from $(2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it is more complicated than a direct proof.  On the set $x\in(2^i,2^{i+1})$, $2^{2i} \le x^2$. So $$LHS \le \sum_i\int_{(2^i,2^{i+1})} |x\hat f|^2  = \int |x\hat f|^2 = \int |\widehat Df|^2 = \int |Df|^2 \le RHS. $$
In order to recover (1) from  (2) you need an additional property of the LP pieces, which is that $\sum_j  \left[\phi\left( \frac{x}{2^j} \right)- \phi\left( \frac{x}{2^{j-1}}\right)\right] ^2\le C$. Then proceed similarly to the direct proof.

Comment: Okay, thnaks for your answer! The property about the LP pieces is a key point! Is the inequality still true if we make the sum in $(1)$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$?

Comment: @prosep yes, thats right